# MS Expression Blend 4  free version for Windows Phone tutorial or example

Tags: expression-blend

I am using the MS Expression Blend 4 for Windows Phone free version from Windoes phone SKD7.1. I serach the web to learn how to use this software. However, I always get the MS Expression Blend project or example that MS Expression Blend 4 for Windows Phone cannot support it. Would someone know the example or tutorial for MS Expression Blend 4 for Windows Phone only. Currently, I would like to create a tempalte for press status for button.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go through the link given below:

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/tags/WindowsPhone/default.aspx

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the answer right here. Then you can still provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: As user has asked for any tutorials or example so I have simply answered with a link which can be useful to Him as a tutorial.